# How do you make a _modified_ copy of an iterable object (any type)?

Tags: python, types, copy, generic-programming, iterable

I would like a function that can make modified copies of iterable objects. I would like it to handle any iterable object. Or or at least any iterable instance of a built-in class. This is what I have so far:

```
def doppelgänger(function, iterable): # FYI, ord('ä') == 228 == 0xe4
    '''Similar to map, except that the return is of the same
    type as iterable, and that there are only two arguments.
    '''
    d = iterable.__new__(type(iterable), map(function, iterable))
    d.__init__(map(function, iterable))
    return d

inc = lambda x: x + 1

doppelgänger(inc, (1,))
# (2,)

doppelgänger(inc, [1])
# [2]

doppelgänger(inc, set([1]))
# {2}

doppelgänger(inc, frozenset((1,)))
# frozenset({2})

doppelgänger(inc, deque([1]))
# deque([2])
```

So far, so good. However:

```
doppelgänger(lambda x: x, 'a')
# '<map object at 0x00000215DA88DC18>'

doppelgänger(lambda x: x, memoryview(bytes(1)))
# Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# File "<stdin>", line 4, in doppelgänger
# TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'map'
```

I suppose I could write a bunch of exceptions to handle things like `str`, `memoryview`, etc., but that seems unpythonic. I have the same sentiment for adding options that might perform the intermediate processing necessary for `__new__` and `__init__` to receive the correct types of arguments, but that, too, seems unpythonic.

Comment: You really shouldn't be calling `__new__` and `__init__` directly in this context, generally, that should only happen in the class / a subclass. Rather, rely on the constructors. In any case, there probably isn't any elegant way to do this, because iterables types have no requirements as to having to accept arbitrary iterables in for their constructors. They simply must implement `__iter__`.

Comment: The iteration protocol provides a common way to *consume* an iterable, regardless of type (i.e., the `next` function). There is nothing comparable for *building* a value of an iterable type.